# How can I download sources for particular Maven artifact in IDEA?

Tags: maven-2, ide, intellij-idea

In [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) there is an opportunity to select a [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) artifact you have a dependency on and download sources or documentation only for it.

Now I am struggling to find that functionality in [IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). But seems to be it provides only opportunity to download sources for ALL dependencies.

Or I am wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Jira issue](http://jetbrains.net/jira/browse/IDEA-14585?disableRedirect) was raised against IDEA to achieve this. However it was closed as a duplicate of [this issue](http://jetbrains.net/jira/browse/IDEADEV-20984?disableRedirect). I think they may have misinterpreted the requirement to download particular sources as being the same as downloading all sources (I think the highlighted button downloads all sources?).

This indicates that there isn't a means to download an individual artifact's sources, sorry.

[download sources screenshot http://jetbrains.net/jira/secure/thumbnail/22603/22603_button.png](http://jetbrains.net/jira/secure/thumbnail/22603/22603_button.png)

Comment: I would elaborate on your issue why the previous issue was closed with improper resolution. Without further information they are likely to close this one too.